# I have a problem with this code that return URL instead of data

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

```
var http = require('http');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var parser = xml2js.Parser({
    explicitArray: false
});

var goodreadsService = function () {
    var getBookById = function (id, cb) {
        var options = {
            host: 'www.goodreads.com',
            path: '/book/show/656?format=xml&key={my developer key}'
        };
        var callback = function (response) {
            var str = '';
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                str += chunk;
            });
            response.on('end', function () {
                console.log(str);
                parser.parseString(str,
                    function (err, result) {
                        cb(null,
                            result.GoodreadsResponse.book);
                    });
            });
        };
        http.get(options, callback).end();
    };
    return {
        getBookById: getBookById
    };
};

module.exports = goodreadsService;
```

This code returns a link

**html bodyYou are being a href http ://www.goodreads.com/book/show/656.War_and_Peace" redirected a bodyhtml**

Instead of xml data in it.
and I dont why ???

Comment: what is `my developer key`?

Comment: format of the code makes it unreadable.

Comment: I do not know why your function would return a string (url) where you are returning an object. In the return statement you supposed to call the `getBookById()` function. But, `getBookById` function returns noting so it should return `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally multiple callbacks style makes things very much confusing. you could either use promises or async/await style. it will make code much cleaner and easier to understand. Look at this

```
var got = require("got");
var xml2js = require("xml2js");
var parser = xml2js.Parser({ explicitArray: false });

async function getById(id) {
  const response = await got("https://goodreads.com/book/show/656?format=xml&key=somekey");
  const json = await parser.parseStringPromise(response.body);
  return json;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you mark that as an answer for other people’s reference?